# How to add data in Excel using GUI Tkinter and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter, project, xlrd

*Hi,
I want to add data to excel sheet by clicking on Add Button. I am using tkinter for GUI and pandas to work with excel. I tried get() method to get data from entry field and add it to excel sheet. But I cant see anything in excel sheet. Please help. My code is as below.*

*===========*

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

def UpdateSheet():
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Match1.xlsx")
   var.get(writer)
   writer.save()

top2=Tk()
top2.geometry("800x800")


var = StringVar()


t2name = Label(top2, text="Team 2 name").place(x=20, y=30)

t2entry = Entry(top2, width=30,textvariable=var).place(x=100, y=30)

sbtbtn2 = Button(top2, text="Submit", activebackground='Orange', activeforeground='Black', 
command=UpdateSheet).place(x=100, y=500)

top2.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see anything even remotely connected to pandas in your code, to be honest. How exactly do you use it?